# algorithm - What does the temperature variable in the Fruchterman and Reingold force-directed graph layout algorithm mean?

Tags: algorithm, layout, graph

I am planning on implementing the Fruchterman and Reingold algorithm for drawing graphs from here: http://cs.brown.edu/people/rtamassi/gdhandbook/chapters/force-directed.pdf , page 5. There is this temperature variable "t" but there is no explanation on what it is, and there is also this "cool(t)" function applied through iterations. Does anyone have any explanation for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is a short description in the article of what the "temperature" variable is:

> The algorithm of Fruchterman and Reingold adds the notion of “temperature” which could be used as follows: “the temperature could start at an initial value (say one tenth the width of the frame) and decay to 0 in an inverse linear fashion.” The temperature controls the displacement of vertices so that as the layout becomes better, the adjustments become smaller. The use of temperature here is a special case of a general technique called simulated annealing, whose use in force-directed algorithms is discussed later in this chapter.

So the algorithm is a variation of the [Simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) technique for searching a global optimum of a function. Here is an intuitive description of the algorithm:

You start with a random state of your problem at *high* temperature. You begin to randomly modify your state, giving preference to new states that improve the function value. At first, because of the high temperature, you allow very huge variations of the current state - including such that do not improve the function value or even make it worse (this helps avoiding getting stuck in a local optimum). With iterations, you reduce the temperature according to some cooling schedule (this is where the `cool(t)` function comes into play), giving more and more preference to the variations that only improve the function value.

There are various subtleties regarding how to choose the initial temperature, the cooling schedule, the acceptance probability for new states, etc. Usually, this is a very problem specific task and it is hard to provide a general approach.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have implemented it but i still have some problems